# How to stop Angular call to Spring webflux stream to be remotely closed

Tags: angular, spring-webflux

I'm learning Spring webflux and Reactive Streams and tried a service that streams infos from mongoDB.
Problem is that when nothing is left to send from MongoDB, Spring close the request.
So what i really wanted to do was:
Having an Angular table showing the datas retrieved by SPRING in my mongodb, and each time an update/insert is made, having the new datas coming automatically to Angular.

The only way i found was by calling my angular service every XXXX milliseconds.

Is there any other way to do this?
So here is my Spring webservice code:

```
@GetMapping(path="/stream/organisation",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Organisation> streamAll() {
    return organisationRepository.findAll();
}
```

My Angular service:

```
getOrganisationStream(): Observable<Array<Organisation>> {
    this.Organisations = [];
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
            const eventSource = new EventSource(this.url);
            eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                console.debug('Received event: ', event);
                const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(json);
                const org: Organisation = new Organisation();
                org.codeFase = json.codeFase;
                org.id = json.id;
                org.name = json.name;
                this.Organisations.push(org);
                console.log(this.Organisations.length);
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    observer.next(this.Organisations);
                });
            };
            eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
                if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
                console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
                eventSource.close();
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

My component:

```
organisations: Observable<Organisation[]>;
constructor(private testService: TestService) {
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.organisations = this.testService.getOrganisationStream();
}
```

My HTML:

```
   <div *ngFor="let org of organisations | async"> 
{{org.name}} {{org.codeFase}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [tailable cursor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#tailable-cursors.reactive) it's an infinit stream it remains open until it is closed externally.

In your repository do something like:

```
@Tailable
Flux<Organisation> findAll();
```

The cursor will be close when supscription is discard, in your case when client close connection.

Comment: Thanks it works just fine. Shame i need a capped collection :'( But it works!!

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it.